# want to hide payment option and directly redirect to payment page (cc avanue page)

Tags: checkout, payment

[image]
I don't want last step because I only have one payment option how to go to payment page from shipping information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found answer add simple js done the trick

add below line in script    app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml

```
payment.save();
```

and add below line in script app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/button.phtml

```
 setTimeout(function(){
      review.save();
    }, 100);
```

> *note:  I already hide product review step in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml